# How to align an array of floats in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, alignment, simd

I want to align an array of floats on 16-byte boundaries in C#.

One technique I am aware of is to pin the array:
http://meekmaak.blogspot.ca/2010/06/c-memory-aligned-array-wrapper-for-fast.html

I didn't like the idea of pinning the memory. I am concerned about how it might affect performance of the garbage collection.

Are there other techniques? I was thinking of creating a 16-byte structure, allocating an array of it, and then casting the array to an array of floats.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Float4 {
    [FieldOffset(0)]  public float X;
    [FieldOffset(4)]  public float Y;
    [FieldOffset(8)]  public float Z;
    [FieldOffset(12)] public float W;
}
```

I'm not sure what I would do next (castings between different types of arrays) and what the best approach is?

Comment: That structure looks to me like it has alignment of 4. The use of `FieldOffset` seems rather pointless. How else do you think the compiler will lay it out? The code you link to looks reasonable. I don't think you'll get anywhere with a managed type. Why would .net align your structures on 16 byte boundaries? Native code looks pretty good here.

Comment: Side note: C# is not C++. Your idea of casting a byte[] to a float[] is not working like that in C#. Also, the StructLayout attribute does not pin a struct...

Comment: For what reason are you trying to align to the 16B boundary?

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon what you're doing, it might make sense to use a structure with explicit layout which includes at least one `long` or `double` overlaid with your `float` variables (I think the verifier will allow that, but I'm not sure) or use some manually-managed memory.  An array which contains over about 22,000 floats will be allocate don the Large Object Heap; I think an array which contains IIRC 2,000 will also be likewise aligned, but I don't know if that treatment applies on 64-bit systems or whether it would apply to arrays of structures containing doubles.  If your arrays aren't large enough to "belong" on the Large Object Heap, you may need to allocate a large array and manually sub-allocate pieces of it to various consumers.

On some versions of .NET, it might have been possible to allocate an array with three extra elements and use a DLL which accepts a `float` by reference, reports bits 2-3 of its address, and shift floats around in an array to ensure proper alignment (e.g. if you want an array of 256 values, allocate 259, and if the DLL reports that `arr[0]` is at address 0x12345ABC, use array slots #1-#256).  The difficulty with such an approach is that the GC may arbitrarily move things around from time to time, and one might thus have to periodically move elements up or down in the array so as to correct their alignment.  Further, I don't know if it's possible to force the marshaller to do a real "pass-by-reference", rather than substituting "pass-by-value-result" [the latter passing the address of a temporary buffer, rather than the array element].  By my understanding, some version of .NET are prone to make that substitution.

I'm personally somewhat puzzled by why .NET doesn't make significant effort to align most objects with cache lines.  Blindly padding objects to the next 16-byte multiple would at worst waste an extra 60% of space (the worst-case being a 20-byte object padded to 32); adding some special-case logic for 12-, 20-, and 24-byte objects could cut the worst-case overhead to 14%.  Since most object usages are preceded by an access to their type reference, having first few bytes of field data in the same cache line would seem like a performance win.

Comment: Adding a long or double would generally only cause alignment to occur on 8 byte boundaries, right?

Comment: @cdiggins: Yeah. I guess it probably would, though an array of 2000 or more doubles will get allocated on the Large Object Heap.  An LOH allocation would satisfy requirements; I don't know why there's no way to explicitly request one.